# Run a command at the start of XRDP session

Tags: keyboard-layout, remote-desktop, xrdp

**Update** actually /etc/xrdp/reconnectwm.sh *does* get executed at reconnect but the setxkbmap options do not "take".

..

I'm using single board computer(s) over (x)rdp. This is all working okay EXCEPT I cannot make setxkbmap run when reconnecting to xrdp session.

There are various configuration files which seem to be executed at startup. .profile is executed for login shell and sticking the setxkbmap there gives you UK/Finnish keyboard when you first start a shell.

But when you close your remote desktop and reconnect later, it's back to US keyboard. I know I could overwrite the US keyboard file in /etc/xrdp but that's not very elegant solution plus I lose the ability to switch between keyboards with shift-alt.

For those interested, I have the lines

```
setxkbmap -layout "gb,se"
setxkbmap -option "grp:alt_shift_toggle"
```

in .profile and .bashrc. So after reconnecting I can open a terminal and it restores the keyboard..

Surely there must be a script that is executed when remote connection is re-established? there's reconnectwm.sh in /etc/xrdp but it won't work of course.

Comment: Hit this issue again with another box. Seems to be alive and well, add the setxkbmap lines to reconnectwm.sh and it does nothing. Put them into a separate script file and source it from the reconnectwm.sh and it works. Incidentally, the source line needs full pathname to the script so it seems reconnectwm.sh is not actually executed in the /etc/xrdp directory.

Comment: I'm so glad I found this question. This is the exact same chain of problems and solutions I was encountering (also with an SBC). Sourcing the above snippet via an external script (_e.g_ from `/usr/local/bin`) does seem to be the least ugly solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having the same problem, solved by adding in /etc/xrdp/reconnectwm.sh " sleep 2s " before " setxkbmap " command.

Wrong way, but it works.

Comment: This seems to do the trick. I guess it depends on your remote box how long the sleep should be. I would imagine the problem is that "something" is getting executed at the same time as reconnectwm.sh is called and overwrites the changes to the keyboard. Add a delay and you get the last word.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a way to make this happen.

If I source another script from the reconnectwm.sh that contains the the setxkbmap commands, it *will* stick.

Weird, but hey, it works!

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth trying to set the values system wide by editing `/etc/default/keyboard`:

```
XKBLAYOUT=gb,se
XKBOPTIONS=grp:alt_shift_toggle
```

Should be effective after next reboot.

With that you should be able to drop the `setxkbmap` calls in `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately. Oddly enough faffing with the default keyboard and locale makes reconnect work as expected.. *once*. After that you get US keyboard again. reconnectwm.sh does get executed, I verified by creating a text file with it. However the setxkbmap commands have no effect so it seems they're being overridden.

Comment: starting another script with the keyboard layout commands actually does work. Why? I have no idea.

Comment: @Barleyman: Sounds weird. Anyway, I'm glad you found a way to fix it.

Comment: Igor's suggestion about adding a sleep into the reconnectwm.sh seems to work. Probably calling another script has similar effect. It appears there's some kind of race condition which is resolved by delaying the execution of the keyboard setup.